# Cold water frozen, hot drips but does not improve

Tags: plumbing, freezing

Very cold weather and a mobile home; last week both shower supply lines froze, then thawed a few days later. Since that time we've run a light drip (cold water only, unfortunately) and every few hours run the hot water on full for a minute or so.

Last night at 4 AM or so I ran the hot water for a minute with normal pressure (hot and cold behaved properly). I then cut it down to a drip and went back to bed. At 6:30 (and zero with a windchill to -15 or so) I had no cold water and the hot water was merely dripping at full throttle. I assume that I must have positioned the handle just a bit too far towards 'off' so as to have no drip at all, and that the cold water supply line fully froze and the hot water line partially froze.

I let the hot water run, thinking that it was NEARLY frozen and running it would melt the partial blockage. It remained at the same drip for over an hour. Cold water still does not work.

Should I assume a sediment problem in the controller at this point? We have had pump work done recently and had some dirt in the lines at one point. I will disassemble the controller this evening, but would appreciate a judgment call from someone who knows what they're talking about. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the drips you are getting out of the hot water actually hot?  If the drips are really cold, then you may just not have melted the frozen pipes yet.

Answer (score 4):

If the cold water supply **to** the water heater is frozen, there's not going to be much/any pressure to push water through. Typical mobile home freezup is the supply line **to** the mobile home, not as much the pipes inside the mobile home. The three feet or so between the floor and the ground is a prime area for freezing and usually requires insulation and heat tapes to be reliable in winter.